# How can I move all my CSS box shadows back under div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have a 3D - Paper like effect on a div, this has been created with multiple `box-shadow` properties. What I don't know how to do is to animate them so when I hover the div, they all slide back under. Thinking about CSS animations or jQuery/javascript. Any would be fine.
HTML:

```
<div class = "project">
      <p>Our very own JS library
        <br />
        <br />
        Still working on it
        <br />
        <span class = "platforms">
                    <i class = "fa fa-cogs fa-3x" id = "swing"></i>
                </span>
      </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.project {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    min-height: 300px;
    color: #007fff;
    padding: 1%;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px #fff, 5px 5px #ccc, 9px 9px #fff, 10px 10px #ccc, 14px 14px #fff;
}
```

Result: 
[image: div 3d effect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `transition` css property. Like this:

```
 transition: box-shadow 1s;
```

followed by the box-shadow you want on `:hover`. Maybe something like this:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #ccc, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #ccc, 0 0 #fff;
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/prt8b48a/2)

If you want, you can play around with `transition-timing-function` as well to adjust the animation type. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp).

```css
.project {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    min-height: 300px;
    color: #007fff;
    padding: 1%;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px #fff, 5px 5px #ccc, 9px 9px #fff, 10px 10px #ccc, 14px 14px #fff;
}

.project:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #ccc, 0 0 #fff, 0 0 #ccc, 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class = "project">
  <p>Our very own JS library
    <br />
    <br />
    Still working on it
    <br />
    <span class = "platforms">
      <i class = "fa fa-cogs fa-3x" id = "swing"></i>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @lesssugar, this is what I was gonna suggest at first, but having `box-shadow: none`  would make the color fade out during animation. My solution only "moves" the shadow under. In this particular implementation, it's hardly noticable however.

Comment: @FlipFloop, glad it helped! If it answer your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Good answer ! You can set the transition only in the base state, and have a simpler style.